# Jenkins: Sharing variables in MultiJob

Tags: jenkins, parameter-passing

I'm using Jenkins for testing/build purposes, so I created a MultiJob project with this configuration:

1. Test Job
2. Build Job
3. Install Job

The MultiJob is launched from the Master Jenkins, but other jobs are launched from other Nodes.
The Build Job executes a shell script which creates the BUILD_ID.
Now, I want the BUILD_ID to be passed as parameter to the Install Job.
How can I do that? My only choice is to use a property file?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the suggestion i am going to describe, you will need [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin. One way to pass custom parameter to a downstream job is by storing the key & value pair (`key=value`) in a file and specifying the same file by selecting `Parameters from properties file` option while calling downstream (in this example, job B) job. Refer the screenshot below:

[image]

Now you can access the variable in downstream job 'B' by using `$BUILD_ID`. You would also like to enable the option `Don't trigger if any files are missing`.

Comment: I see this is accepted answer, does it really answers the question though? I have exactly the same situation as @Ligio which is a **MultiJob** and need to pass argument from _build_ to _deploy_ job. Value comes from _build_ job but _deploy_ job **is not a downstream** job of _build_ job. They are run in sequence indeed but as phases of the parent **MultiJob**. Moreover, they run on different slave machines. I can't see how this solution would work. Any tips would be appreciated. [It looks like that.](https://s21.postimg.org/x82wux0qv/multijob.png)

Comment: @topr I have the same issue too. Any progress or workaround on that??

Comment: @polavishnu Yes, each phase job has a few env variables added on the multi job level. For the case in the question it would be sufficient to pass a value of BUILD_JOB_BUILD_ID (or BUILD_JOB_BUILD_NUMBER, don't remember exactly) environment variable to the Install Job.

Comment: My problem is that in my build phase I have to jobs building release and debug. But the name of the job is the same. Kind of the build is set by parameters.
But in the deploy phase I need to copy the artefacts from the build_job (building the debug) and build_job (building release). :/

Answer (score 12):

The question asks how to pass values between jobs for MultiJob projects, not Parameterized Trigger. Parameterized Trigger might not be a good solution because the downstream job will be executed outside of the scope of the MultiJob parent. To pass variables between MultiJob sub-jobs,

1. Write variables to a property file in the first sub-job
2. "Archive the artifacts" as post-build action in the first sub-job
3. Between the first and second sub-jobs, insert an "Copy artifacts from another project" build. Set Project Name to the name of your first sub-job and Which Build to "Build triggered by current MultiJob build". Add your property file in "Artifacts to copy".
4. In your second sub-job, under "Advanced...", Add parameters -> Parameters from properties file, and enter your property file name there. Your second phase will now have variables passed from your first phase.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the parameter `BUILD_ID` by using *Predefined parameters* option in the multi-job phase.

Steps are as follows:

- Go to configure page, by clicking on **Configure** link of your multijob
- Click on **Advanced button** of the job where you want to pass the parameter;
- Click on **Add Parameters**, select **[Predefined parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJ4l.png)**. Then create a parameter name of your own choice and assign the `BUILD_ID` to it;
- Create the same parameter by enabling **[This build is parameterized option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XohqO.png)** in downstream job where you want to receive the defined parameter. Then you can use the same in your script.

Answer (score 1):

First you need add to the "install job" a string parameter called "BUILD_ID" and then once your build job is done you can  "Trigger Parametrized build on on other project "  and add the parameter of the next build being the BUILDID=%BuildID%

For more info on paramterized job on Jenkins read the following link:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

you might need to install a plugin for that. Link above.