# Jenkins - Sending parameters to multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have multiple jobs. Job "A" is start point and then it calls Job "B" AND "C". Jo "B" in turn calls "E,F,G".

I want to pass a string param from A to C and then to G.

I did use the plugin to pass param in post build action from A to C and then to G from C.

I am unable to see it in G. is there a special syntax for multiple jobs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of this question: [Jenkins - passing variables between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs)

You need the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Best answer is @Vinu Joseph:

1.Post-Build Actions > Select ”Trigger parameterized build on other projects”

2.Enter the environment variable with value.Value can also be Jenkins Build Parameters.

Detailed steps can be seen here :-

https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/jenkins-related-articles/jenkins-configuration/jenkins-passing-a-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/

If you're using the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) (which I love), then you can look at this answer:

[Jenkins: Sharing variables in MultiJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929774/jenkins-sharing-variables-in-multijob)